# text color in EditText has different colors

Tags: android, android-edittext, textcolor

[screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Msn.jpg)

As you can see I have written 3 letters and they are pink or whatever this is. I have added these two attributes in the EditText view

> ```
>     android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
>     android:textColor="@color/black"
> ```

where  **edit_text.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#4AB5A7" />
    <stroke android:width="2.5dp"
        android:color="#4AB5A7" />
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

What do i have to do to make them black? Thanks!

Comment: would you paste your @color/black value ?

Comment: <color name="black">#000</color>

Comment: can you try

 android:background="#4AB5A7"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
"
this is not show the rounded cornor, but I hope will give you some quick fix

Comment: its still the same :( . The funny thing is when i write for example "ash" , the color is black . But when i write "ashu" its pink

Comment: I hope, there is no TextWatcher listener in Java class

Comment: nope there is not

Comment: can you check that you do not have a global theme or style that maybe affecting the textColor of the editText? I have tested the 'edit_text.xml' and it looks fine to me.